# How can I make vim indent dplyr code with the pipe (%>%) operator correctly?

Tags: r, vim, indentation, dplyr, magrittr

For example, vim will **not** indent correctly the following code:

```
flights <- flights %>%
    group_by(year, month, day) %>%
    select(arr_delay, dep_delay) %>%
    summarise(
        arr = mean(arr_delay, na.rm = TRUE),
        dep = mean(dep_delay, na.rm = TRUE)
    ) %>%
    filter(arr > 30 | dep > 30)
```

Is there a way to fix this?

I'm using the [Vim-R-Plugin](https://github.com/jcfaria/Vim-R-plugin), the related issue is [here](https://github.com/jcfaria/Vim-R-plugin/issues/160).

Comment: are you using `:set smartindent`?

Answer (score 3):

One thing you can do is learn vimscript and modify this behavior yourself.  If it works well, you can contribute the change to the original author.

I started out this way but ended up writing my own indent code from scratch that does everything just the way I like it.  I talked with the R plugin author about replacing his code with mine but my code has a couple of bugs I've never taken the time to find and that don't bother me much (it gets stuck if you have an unmatched close curly bracket, for example).  I never got the motivation to clean it up the rest of the way and try and get it into the VIM repository.

In response to your query, [I have put my code on github](https://github.com/gvfarns/r_indent_gvf).  You can try using my indent code instead of the r-plugin code if you want.  It may or may not solve your issue (no promises).  If I get motivated enough I may fix it up enough that we could make it the default vim indent code.